# Tomcat catalina.out File

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

Does anyone know what the following entry means in the catalina.out file?  Sometimes there will be a bunch of them and I am wondering if there is some process creating the request?  I am not able to "manually" create the "-" in my browser request.  The "400" Bad Requests that I create look different.

10.14.99.69 - - [11/Feb/2022:20:12:44 +0000] "-" 400 -

Normal log entry.

10.13.23.7 - - [11/Feb/2022:20:15:23 +0000] "GET /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.web.LoginPage?error=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2167

Comment: Is this catalina.out or your access log? (Or are you logging accesses to stdout?)

Comment: Is 10.14.99.69 possibly your load-balancer? It might be a "ping" from the LB to check of the node is live.

Comment: It is the access log.  The requests repeat from the same IP address for a while, but then different IP addresses will pop up doing the same thing.